# installing tomcat on a vps

Tags: linux, vps

I have just bought a Linux VPS and the current setup seems to be apache. The HTML files are stored on

> /var/www

I want to install tomcat on this server. I don't understand where I should install this so when I am on my domain I want to use the tomcat server instead of what is in the `/var/www/` folder.

This is the first time I have used a VPS so I a little confused on where to install software.

Does it matter where it is installed as long as I use port 8080?

Comment: What do you mean by `I want to use the tomcat server instead of what is in the /var/www/ folder`?

Comment: What I mean is when I go to www.domain.com it will run the files in my tomcat webapps folder

Comment: There's nothing magical about it being a VPS. Configure it as you'd configure any server. If you don't know how, then you shouldn't have bought it.

Answer (score 0):

decide what should run on you VPS server:

- a Webserver, typically apache (I will assume it's apache in your case, for simplicity)
- your tomcat webcontainer or servlet container.
- both

These server program are a little different in what they do and what they should be used for. Apache is great for serving static content, but can not execute your WAR files. It may be coupled with a tomcat, so apache delegates sone URI-Paths to the tomcat.

Tomcat runs you webapp, that is usually an Java WAR.

No two server can listen on the same port of the same machine (this is a little simplification, but matches the question), so you have to decide which server you want to call.

I assume that you have found the documentation to apache and tomcat.